# Kotlin equivalent for java: Class<? extends A>

Tags: kotlin, generics

Let's say i have classes A as am abstract parent class while B & C extends it.
I wanna create a function with an option to input classes B & C, like the childs of A (or A itself)

In java I would just have to define a type as `Class<? : Extends A>`
In Kotlin I can do `KClass<*>`, but it seems like too much freedom.

How can I limit the options only for the childs of A?

Comment: you can read a detailed info about Kotlin Generics here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html , this will answer all your questions about kotlin generics

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin if you `KClass<*>` will accept all the classes. If you define with `KClass<A>` will accept only `A` class. In order to accept A and its children, you have defined `KClass<out A>`. See the example below

```
abstract class A
class B:A()
class C:A()

fun method (param : KClass<out A>){}

method(B::class)
```